# LDAPS handshake failure errno 21 Is a directory - Encountered end of file

Tags: centos, openldap, tls

I have set up a **CentOS 7 openLDAP passthrough authentication server**.

It will authenticate users through LDAP on a database hosted on Microsoft active directory.

I can get a successful query response if I use LDAP://

However, LDAPS:// will give certificate handshake errors.

I am using a certificate purchased from GoDaddy in PFX format.

I found a few possible solutions but nothing works so far.

I have tried:

1. Disabling SELinux for testing
2. Converted the PFX cert to PEM as well as DER
3. Used certutil as explained here to make a MozNSS DB:
   http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/1514.html

   pk12util -d /path/to/certdb -i /path/to/file.p12

I found this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13732826/convert-pem-to-crt-and-key
But I don't know what commands to use to get the right format cert for openLDAP.

I have tried these:

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in certificate.pem -out certificate.der
openssl x509 -outform der -in certificate.pem -out certificate.crt
```

When I run a ldapsearch:

```
ldapsearch -H ldaps://192.168.1.69 -b "OU=Administration,DC=domain,DC=com" -v -LLL -D "CN=ServiceLDAP,OU=Administration,DC=domain,DC=com" "(samaccountname=someuser)" -w secretpass -d1
```

These are the errors I am getting:

```
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldaps://192.168.1.32)
ldap_initialize( ldaps://192.168.1.32:636/??base )
ldap_create
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldaps://192.168.1.32:636/??base)
ldap_sasl_bind
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP 192.168.1.32:636
ldap_new_socket: 4
ldap_prepare_socket: 4
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying 192.168.1.32:636
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 4 tm: -1 async: 0
attempting to connect:
connect success
TLS: certdb config: configDir='/etc/openldap/certs' tokenDescription='ldap(0)' certPrefix='' keyPrefix='' flags=readOnly
TLS: using moznss security dir /etc/openldap/certs prefix .
TLS: error: tlsm_PR_Recv returned 0 - error 21:Is a directory
TLS: error: connect - force handshake failure: errno 21 - moznss error -5938
TLS: can't connect: TLS error -5938:Encountered end of file.
ldap_err2string
ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue.

The correct format for the cert and key:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in ./ACertFromGoDaddy.pfx -nocerts -out privatekey.pem -nodes
openssl pkcs12 -in ./ACertFromGoDaddy.pfx -nokeys -out publiccert.pem -nodes
```

I placed those certs in ./openldap/certs and I was able to configure slapd to read them from there by making an ldif file and loading it with slapadd:

`slapadd -n0 -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d/ -l ./mod_ssl.ldif`

My mod_ssl.ldif file's contents are:

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcTLSCACertificateFile
olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/openldap/certs/publiccert.pem
-
add: olcTLSCertificateFile
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/openldap/certs/publiccert.pem
-
add: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/openldap/certs/privatekey.pem
```

I was then able to perform ldap searches locally and remotely:

```
ldapsearch -H ldaps://192.168.1.69 -b "OU=Administration,DC=domain,DC=com" -v -LLL -D "CN=ServiceLDAP,OU=Administration,DC=domain,DC=com" "(samaccountname=someuser)" -w secretpass -d1
```